# How to write dynamic url method in laravel routes file?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a bunch of routes list that are mentioned below for your reference. I have to make it as dynamically.

**Example:**

First set of Routes

```
Route::get('artists/info', 'ArtistApiController@getInfo');
Route::post('artists/records', 'ArtistApiController@postRecords');
Route::post('artists/action', 'ArtistApiController@postAction');
Route::post('artists', 'ArtistApiController@postAdd');
Route::put('artists/update/{id}', 'ArtistApiController@postAdd');
Route::post('artists/update-status/{id}', 'ArtistApiController@postUpdateStatus');
```

Second set of Routes

```
Route::get('albums/info', 'AlbumApiController@getInfo');
Route::post('albums/records', 'AlbumApiController@postRecords');
Route::post('albums/action', 'AlbumApiController@postAction');
Route::post('albums', 'AlbumApiController@postAdd');
Route::put('albums/update/{id}', 'AlbumApiController@postAdd');
Route::post('albums/update-status/{id}', 'AlbumApiController@postUpdateStatus');
```

It seems both the routes list are same except the keyword "albums,artists,AlbumApiController, ArtistApiController". So I need to make it dynamically in order to resuse of that code by passing required parameters. So that it looks like below or whatever syntax let it be.

```
grid('albums', 'AlbumApiController');
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: this is sightly out of context ,  but you could always create one catch all route,  that calls one controller action.  Then u have a DB table with all your routes stored and a column what action/controller to use, etc...

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
foreach (['artists' => 'ArtistApiController', 'albums' => 'AlbumApiController'] as $route => $controller) {
    Route::get($route . '/info', $controller . '@getInfo');
    Route::post($route . '/records', $controller . '@postRecords');
    Route::post($route . '/action', $controller . '@postAction');
    Route::post($route, $controller . '@postAdd');
    Route::put($route . '/update/{id}', $controller . '@postAdd');
    Route::post($route . '/update-status/{id}', $controller . '@postUpdateStatus');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need them to be dynamic? If not, then I would suggest to leave them as they are now... Basically the routes files gives you a brief overview of the structure of your app, so, it would be a good idea to keep your routes as readable as possible.